# How to write query for optional parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have six parameters in Report Builder. They are the following:

- ProjectName
- ConstructionYear
- Engineer
- Contractor
- EPANumber
- ID

@ProjectName, @ConstructionYear, and @EPANumber do not have any null values in the dataset while the rest do have null values for some records.

For the report I need to be able to pull records using any of the above combinations. Including only using one parameter, two parameters, three parameters, etc.

For example using @ProjectName and @EPANumber to pull results or using @ProjectName, @EPANumer, and @ID to pull results. Another example would be using @ConstructionYear and @Engineer or using just @Contractor.

What does my query need to look like to be able to support all of the possible combinations? Do the parameters in Report Builder need to be set up in a certain way?

Comment: Look into Kitchen Sink / Catch-all query solutions eg [this](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/), and [this](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/the-only-thing-worse-than-optional-parameters/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!